# c# - itext7 - Acroform fields not reading - from file

Tags: c#, forms, pdf, field, itext7

there is a PDF file whose fields I am trying to read and populate populate.
(https://bsaefiling1.fincen.treas.gov/DownloadSaveServlet)

So far I have below

```
using iText;
using iText.Pdfa;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Forms.Fields;
using iText.Kernel.Font;

namespace PDfTest
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfProcessor pdfFile = new PdfProcessor();
        pdfFile.PDFFindFields();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class PdfProcessor
{
    public void PDFFindFields ()
    {
        var SourceFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:/Users/e240160/Desktop/NFFBAR.pdf");
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SourceFileStream), new PdfWriter(outputStream));
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
        var fandannot = form.GetAllFormFieldsAndAnnotations();
        foreach (var de in form.GetAllFormFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(de.Key + " - " + de.Value);
        }



}
}
```

I have tested my script with other template files and it seems to be working fine - fields in the form are readily identified - but not with this file.

Can you please point me in the right direction ? - what property do i need to change to get it to work ?

Comment: What is the error message and could you post also a working pdf?

Comment: What is the use of the var fandannot? It's not used after.

Comment: @Fredy , there is no error message - there are simply no fields in the ACROFORM object.

Comment: @Fredy var fandannot - this was just something i tried to replace form variable with during debugging

Comment: @Fredy this is one of many examples with the working file http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the example. I tried it and it does read the de.Key but not the de.Value. This one return things like "iText.Forms.Fields.PdfTextFormField"